# Rotating iptables logs, strange message about script being converted to upstart job

Tags: logs, cron, upstart, logrotate

I use a script `/etc/logrotate.d/iptables` containing entries like:

```
/var/log/in_iptables.log
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

to keep my iptables logs rotated.

It seems to have been doing its job, but today I got a message from `anacron`:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but rotate is not supported for Upstart jobs.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rsyslog, action "rotate" failed.
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/in_iptables.log
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

Can anyone explain to me what this means exactly? Do I need to be worried or change anything in order for my logs to keep rotating?

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be because `rsyslog` has been converted to an Upstart service now, so can't use the old `invoke-rc.d` command. Given this postrotate command execution is simply to reload the config of rsyslog so it stops writing to the old logfile (which has now been compressed), I think the new upstart way of doing this would be:

```
service rsyslog reload > /dev/null
```

Although I wonder if there is a way to make a "rotate" action work (not sure what benefit a rotate action would provide vs a simple reload anyway?)

As I understand it "rotate" is a custom action provided by logrotate.